# JetBrains Rider - move line up / down hotkey

Tags: jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

I've just installed a trial version of JetBrains Rider, migrated my settings from Visual Studio.

However, the hotkey for moving line up or down via `Alt` + `↑` / `Alt` + `↓` doesn't work. It instead moves the caret 1 block up. The problem is that I've tried mapping "Move line up" using the Keymap settings, but I don't see them anywhere. I am literally unable to map "Move line up" to a hotkey in Rider.

[image: It's present in the Code tab of Rider, though]

[image: It doesn't display the option in Keymap]

Comment: *"...but I don't see them anywhere.*" -- it is below (you need to scroll it down a bit) -- check under "Main Menu | Code" node on your Keymap screen: https://i.imgur.com/URcDBwS.png

Comment: Wow.... Just wow... So... Let's display everything except the options that literally match what I searched for. Thanks @LazyOne

Comment: Try it as a one word (no spaces) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I can't mark @LazyOne's comment as an answer, I'll have to post on my own.

Long story short, the solution was to literally scroll to the very end after searching for "Move line". Rider's search seems to be kind of odd. It highlighted every option properly, but it didn't filter them all out, so I had to manually find "Move line down" in the results.